# Controlling Servos with Blender Arduino

Tags: scripting

I am making an animatronic using an arduino and I wan tot control the servos with blender. I have looked through every post an tutorial and nothing seems to work (I am a complete blender noob) I want the rotation of a servo to change with the rotation of a cube here is the python code I have

```
import bpy
from math import degrees
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('COM5', baudrate = 9600, timeout = 1)
def cube_rot_report(scene):
    cube = scene.objects.get("Cube")
    if cube:
        #rot = cube.matrix_world.to_euler()
        rot = cube.rotation_euler
        ser.write([degrees(r) for r in rot])

clear the handlers
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.clear()

bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post.append(cube_rot_report)
```

here is my arduino code

```
 #include <Servo.h>

    // Servos to be used
    Servo servo1;
    int pos = 0;    // variable to store the servo position 

    void setup()
    {
      // This is using pin 9 (change accordingly)
      servo1.attach(9);  // attaches the servo on pin 9 to the servo object 
      pinMode(13, OUTPUT); //LED
      // initialize the serial port
      Serial.begin(9600);
      servo1.write(45); //initial servo position
    }

    int angle, light=0;

    void loop()
    {  
      // wait for the servo angle
      if(Serial.available() > 0){
        angle = Serial.read();
        servo1.write(angle);
        if (light==0) { 
          digitalWrite(13, HIGH); 
          light=1;   // set the LED on 
        }
        else { 
          digitalWrite(13, LOW);
          light =0;    // set the LED off
        }
      }
    }
```

please help! :)

Comment: Do you get any console errors from blender? Do you need a `ser.open()`? Can a non-blender script write a set sequence of data to the serial port? Can blender run the same script without using a handler? In blender `ser.write` is sending an array of three float values, while the matching `servo1.write` is sending all three values to the servo. Does the servo work if the data sent is larger than it uses?

Comment: I do not need a serial open but I think the three values is the issue thank you!